# AppendChild Form / Table [Javascript/Html/PHP]

Tags: javascript, php, html-table, appendchild

My main issue is that I have a really nicely set up ability to add forms/remove them HOWEVER, the problem is that Doing one type of append will make the inputs show up (exactly how I want it) but not actually be added to the form while the other makes the form invisible however you can see it pop up on the `$_POST`.

```
<script language="javascript">
    function addRow(tableID,texting,values) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.type = "checkbox";
        cell1.appendChild(element1);

        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell2.innerHTML = texting+":";

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var element2 = document.createElement("input");
        element2.type = "text";
        element2.name = texting; // Change this dummy.
        if(tableID == "levelup")
            element2.name += "rate";
        if(values != "" && values != null && values != "undefined")
            element2.value = values;
        cell3.appendChild(element2); //This isn't hidden but no works, wat?
        //document.forms[1].appendChild(element2); //This works but is hidden
        //document.forms[1].write("hi!");

    }



    function deleteRow(tableID) {
        try {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;

            for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
                var row = table.rows[i];
                var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
                if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                    table.deleteRow(i);
                    rowCount--;
                    i--;
                }


            }
        }catch(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }
</script>
<html>
    <table>
        <tr><td>Add statistic:</td></tr>
        <form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
            <tr><td><input type="text" name="addme"><input type="button" value="add" onclick="addRow('formulas',document.forms[0].addme.value); addRow('levelup',document.forms[0].addme.value,'1+'+document.forms[0].addme.value)"/></td><td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow('formulas'); deleteRow('levelup')"/></td></tr>
        </form>
        <form action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
            <tr><td>Formula name:</td><td><input type="text" name="formulaname"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Statistics at level 1(required)</td></tr>
            <tr>
            <table>
                <tr><td>Level 1:</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Move speed:</td><td><input type="text" value="1" name="movespeed"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Stats:</td></tr>
                <tr><td><table id="formulas"></table></td></tr>
            </table></tr>
            <tr><td>Level up Formula Rates</td></tr>
            <table>
                <tr><td>Move speed:</td><td><input type="text" value="Mov+1" name="Movrate"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Experience:</td><td><input type="text" value="(Exp*0.25)*Exp*Lvl+(0.25*Mov)" name="Exprate"></td></tr>
                <tr><td><table id="levelup"></table></td></tr>
            </table>
            <tr><td><input type="submit"  value="Save"/></td></tr>
        </form>
    </table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't work because you append a new row outside the form. Split your table into two separate tables, one for the first form and one for the second. Then wrap the tables in the form tags that are currently inside it.

The result should have the following structure:

```
<form>
  <table> (add statistics form) </table>
</form>
<form>
  <table> (formulas) </table>
</form>
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, I COULD KISS YOU

Comment: If anyone wants to use this code, feel free it's a good script for adding a formatted form or removing it.